# How can I get git in sync with remote master branch

Tags: django, git

I'm confused about why my production server seems to think it is ahead of my master branch.  I use fabric to deploy, and it runs a git pull on the server from my master branch on github.  I make no changes that I'm aware of on the production server itself, and I certainly do not make commits on the production server.

`git status` yields:

```
  # On branch master
  # Your branch is ahead of 'github/master' by 57 commits.
  #
  nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

As far as I can tell, what's on the production server matches the master branch on in my dev environment.  At least the site acts the same, but I find this disconcerting.  Any ideas on how to get the production repository on the same page as github master and stop giving me this message?

Edit (4/11/2013):

Just to clarify, when I use fabric to deploy, it runs:

`git pull github master`  on the server.

My git status results written above in the original question, are on the server.  I NEVER make commits on the server, only in my dev environment, which I push to github, which are in turn pulled to the server.  That's why I'm confused.  I certainly don't want to push anything from my production server to github, that's the opposite direction of my workflow.

2nd Edit (4/11/2013):

here's the fabfile git code:

```
def prepare_remote_deployment_area():
    """Prepare the production host with updated resources"""
    with cd(DEPLOYMENT_ROOT):
        run('git pull github master')
```

this is called from deploy:

```
def deploy():
    """Deploy an update (committed to GitHub) to production"""
    check_git_status()
    check_git_status(on_remote=True)
    prepare_remote_deployment_area()
    restart_uwsgi()
    restart_nginx()
    restart_celery()
```

Again, this all seems to work in the sense that the changes I make in my dev environment show up on production.  I just don't understand why the production repository thinks it's so far ahead of github master.

Comment: Yes - it is fine - YOu have changes in your local master which need to be pushed into the remote. Just do a `git pull origin master` followed by `git fetch --all`

Comment: did you create your own fabfile.py?

Comment: added details for catherine's question in 2nd edit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`git pull`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)

```
git pull origin master
```

More info

```
NAME
       git-pull - Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local
       branch

DESCRIPTION
       Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current
       branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch
       followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.
```